# Compare response in jest unit test case

Tags: javascript, jestjs, ts-jest

I'm new to jest unit test case scenario, I have a scenario where in the response from the service that I called is of the below format

```
Artifact {
        name: 'detection-v1.zip',
        file_path: 'artifact\\bn-ds-anomalydetection-v1.zip',
        is_tenant: false,
        metadata: [
          Registerfact {
            name: 'ad',
            _meta: [Object],
            line_meta: [Object]
          },
          Registerfact {
            name: 'ad-generic',
            _meta: [Object],
            line_meta: [Object]
          }
        ]
      }
```

how can i compare the above response in the jest service , I was trying to  create a object but the Artifact name before the object is confusing how should i proceed

The test case is

```
test('test processArtifact method', async()=>{
    const mockGetRestClient = jest.fn();
    
    try{
      const response = await factService.processfact(artifact)
      console.log("response---",response)
      // expect(response).toEqual()
    }
    catch(e){ }
  })
```

I know its silly question ,but i'm confused hence posted it.

How should i create the static object to be put in .toEqual() ?

Answer (score 1):

You can declare a global/static var with your response object on top of file. Or better declare it in some constants file and import here.

**For Comparison:**
Usually, if you have a simple object, you can use `JSON.stringify`. However, it may give error due to different order of object keys.

You should use [assert](https://nodejs.org/api/assert.html#assertdeepequalactual-expected-message) for the deep comparison. There is method `assert.deepEqual()` which does deep comparison of objects.

an example for using assert from [official docs](https://nodejs.org/api/assert.html#assertdeepequalactual-expected-message)

```
import assert from 'node:assert';

const obj1 = {
  a: {
    b: 1
  }
};
const obj2 = {
  a: {
    b: 2
  }
};
const obj3 = {
  a: {
    b: 1
  }
};
const obj4 = Object.create(obj1);

assert.deepEqual(obj1, obj1);
// OK

// Values of b are different:
assert.deepEqual(obj1, obj2);
// AssertionError: { a: { b: 1 } } deepEqual { a: { b: 2 } }

assert.deepEqual(obj1, obj3);
// OK

// Prototypes are ignored:
assert.deepEqual(obj1, obj4);
// AssertionError: { a: { b: 1 } } deepEqual {}
```

Hope this helps, let me know if you have any questions.

Answer (score -1):

You can use `JSON.stringify` in order to convert your object into a string and then compare this result to the one you expect.

```js
console.log(JSON.stringify({
        name: 'detection-v1.zip',
        file_path: 'artifact\\bn-ds-anomalydetection-v1.zip',
        is_tenant: false,
        metadata: [
          {Registerfact: {
            name: 'ad',
            _meta: {},
            line_meta: {}
          }},
          {Registerfact: {
            name: 'ad-generic',
            _meta: {},
            line_meta: {}
          }}
        ]
      }));
```

Comment: When using `JSON.stringify` , the ORDER of the properties IS IMPORTANT. It would fail if one key is not in order. e.g  `x = {a: 1, b: 2}; ` and `y = {b: 2, a:1};` are not equal according to this method.

Comment: @WaleedAhmad and what if the order is important?

Comment: Then it should be picked. But in most of the use cases, we don't care about order as we're mostly concerned about getting required key and values in the response.  Also, in the question, it doesn't specifies key should be in exact order.

Comment: @WaleedAhmad when we test something, we test whether everything fits into place, including the order of an array's elements. If you are to write a unit test, by default you should not assume that the order is irrelevant, unless specified otherwise.